# ngRoute not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I am trying to learn about routes in in angular and I am having some trouble getting the proper text to display. It seems that everything is working without errors when I run my page however, the view is not changing from main.html to second.html when I click on the link.

Here are some snips of my code...

```
<html ng-app="myApp">

    <!-- load angular via CDN -->
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" >AngularJS</a>
            </div>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/second"><i></i>Second</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="container">

        <div ng-view></div>

    </div>

</body>
```

main html contents:

```
<h1>This is main</h1>
```

second html contents:

```
<h1>This is second</h1>
```

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ["ngRoute"]);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider

  .when("/", {
    templateUrl: "pages/main.html",
    controller: "mainController"
  })

  .when("/second", {
    templateUrl: "pages/second.html",
    controller: "secondController"
  })

});

myApp.controller('mainController', ["$scope", "$log", "$location",     function($scope, $log, $location) {

}]);

myApp.controller('secondController', ["$scope", "$log", "$location",     function($scope, $log, $location) {

}]);
```

Comment: Please, consider reading this: [http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And you can do the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of stackoverflow

Comment: Thank you! I will

Answer (score 0):

try ui-router instead of ngRoute

I am using it in a lot of projects and its working very good

doc: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Answer (score 0):

At first line in your index.html, you're opening a `<html>` tag, but you're closing with a `</head>` one, plus, I'd recommand placing your `ng-app="myApp"` in the opening `<body>` tag, this way :

```
<head>
    <!-- everything you need -->
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <!-- and stuff -->
</body>
```

If this doesn't change anything after correcting these errors, I really don't know what's the problem, everything looks ok.